# Python exception handling and raising

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, nested, raise

let's say I have the following 3 scripts:

```
script1.py
script2.py
script3.py
```

Lets say I get a traceback like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script1.py", line xyz, in ...
...
File "script2.py", line xyz, in ...
...
File "script3.py", line xyz, in ...
...
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CoolAttribute'
```

I have several different exceptions that occur in script3.py. Is there a way to handle ANY of these exceptions in line xyz in script1.py without handling the exceptions in script2.py? I just want to handle the exceptions that stem from script3.py in one line in script1.py.

Comment: Yes, of course there is a way to do that, but it is better to handle errors closer to the source (where you can generally do something more sensible about them). Could you show a more concrete example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Basically the code in script2.py and script3.py is not mine. Some other people know better how to handle the exceptions. I would just like to count the number of exceptions that occur since I call the line xyz in script1.py multiple times. I just see if I can find a more detailed example but if you know how to achieve this, please don't hesitate to tell me...

Comment: How far have you got? Have you read e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html?

Comment: I did but not completely... I guess I will find it there? So I continue reading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple dirty way to do it is wrap you simple3.py with try except close and raise custom exception on any script3 exceptions.

```
class BaseSimpleError(Exception):
    """dummy class for all Simple3 errors"""

try:
    ...your simple3.py goes here...
except Exception, e:
    raise BaseSimpleError()
```

In script1 you should import BaseSimpleError and catch it when required.

Comment: Hi, I think I get the idea. In the meantime I solved this by reraising the 'Exception' excpetion. Next time I will try out your solution.